# XSL 1.0 How to grab from an external Document

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to grab the node value of an external document, but am nowhere near getting anything that works.

This is the products.xml

```
<TESTS>
<CHILD>
     <KEY>111111</KEY>
     <PRODUCT>Toy 1</PRODUCT>
    </CHILD>
    <CHILD>
     <KEY>222222</KEY>
     <PRODUCT>Toy 2</PRODUCT>
    </CHILD>
</TESTS>
```

This is the file being transformed companys.xml

```
<INVENTORY>
     <PRODUCTS>
     <ITEMS>
          <ITEM TYPE="Toys">111111</ITEM>
     </ITEMS>
 </PRODUCTS>
     <PRODUCTS>
     <ITEMS>
          <ITEM TYPE="Toys">222222</ITEM>
     </ITEMS>
 </PRODUCTS>
<INVENTORY>
```

This is the xsl code I have

```
<xsl:variable name="lookupDoc" select="document('products.xml')" />
<xsl:key name="product-lookup" match="KEY" use="."/>

<xsl:template match="PRODUCT_HTML">
<xsl:value-of select="./@TYPE"/> <xsl:value-of select="."/> <xsl:value-of select="$lookupDoc/exam-lookup" />
</xsl:template>
```

What I am getting from this is

```
Toys 111111
```

What I would Like to get is

```
Toys 111111 Toy 1
```

Can you please help me out?

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xsl:key` element has to be used in conjunction with the `key()` function.

Your key definition

```
<xsl:key name="product-lookup" match="KEY" use="."/>
```

is not quite what you want, I think.  `match` controls the element that you want to return, while `use` tells what expression is being matched in the lookup.  As written, it will return the `KEY` element itself, and to get to the `PRODUCT` you'd have to traverse laterally.  It probably should be

```
<xsl:key name="product-lookup" match="CHILD" use="KEY"/>
```

This way, an expression like

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('product-lookup', '111111') />
```

will point to the first `CHILD` node in the `products.xml` file.  Then you can traverse downward to the product name.

**However**, there's a wrinkle in XSLT 1.0 when using the `key()` function on an external document: `key()` operates on the "context document", so if the current node is in the input document `companys.xml`, the lookup will not give the result you want.

To work around this, you can set the context to the target document, as follows:

```
<xsl:variable name="key" select="." />
<xsl:variable name="child">
    <xsl:for-each select="$lookupDoc">
        <xsl:value-of select="key('product-lookup', $key)/PRODUCT"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

Now `$child` now contain the string value of the `PRODUCT` element under the corresponding `CHILD`. (See comments re variable binding.)

Note that an extra variable is needed to store the key so that `.` doesn't change its meaning when you change the context.  In other words, you have to save a binding to the key value from the original document first.

In XSLT 2.0, you can avoid some of that by using a third parameter that was added to the `key()` function for setting the context document:

```
<xsl:variable name="child" select="key('product-lookup', ., $lookupDoc)" />
```

Makes this (common) problem much cleaner.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I am so close. when I use <xsl:value-of select="$child"/> it prints out Toys 111111111111 Toy 1, so it is grabbing the KEY and the PRODUCT. When I do <xsl:value-of select="$child/PRODUCT"/> I get an XSL tarnsformation error "Cannot use result tree fragmentError in XPath expression, Cannot use result tree fragment" . If I can get it to just print the Toy 1 value of the corresponding PRODUCT node, I'd be set.

Comment: @AlexScript, my mistake.  This has to do with implicit type conversion in XSLT.  A variable binding directly to a node (such as with `select`) will give you a node reference that you can use in later XPath expressions.  But when you use `value-of`, it converts the result to a string.  You have a few options.  If all you want is the product name, you can just tack on the `/PRODUCT` to the `key()` expression and be done (see edit).  Alternatively, you can do further processing inside the `for-each` (if you needed to work with others parts of `CHILD`.  Finally, you could use `node-set` extension.